How to get full citation with natbib?
I am using class memoir to write my thesis
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{autonum,filecontents}
\usepackage[compress]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}

\begin{filecontents}{mytestbib.bib}
@book{goossens93,
    author = "Frank Mittelbach and Michel Goossens  and Johannes Braams and David Carlisle  and Chris Rowley",
    title = "The {LaTeX} Companion",
    year = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document} 

\cite{goossens93}

\bibliography{mytestbib}

\end{document}

I would like to have a full cite of a paper in the body of the thesis. For biblatex, we can use \fullcite{...}. However, I use packages natbib and autonum (which relies on etextools). Could you explain how to have full citation in my case?

Off-topic: Since you're using the natbib package, you should probably be using the unsrtnat bibliography style instead of unsrt. For one, unsrtnat can handle handle a fields named url, whereas the much older unsrt style cannot.

It's not possible to get a full citation with natbib.
You can emulate \fullcite of biblatex with usebib.
Caveat The fields in the .bib file must be delimited with braces; double quotes don't work with usebib.
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{goossens93,
  author = {Frank Mittelbach and Michel Goossens
    and Johannes Braams and David Carlisle  and Chris Rowley},
  title = {The {\LaTeX} Companion},
  year = {1993},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  address = {Reading, Massachusetts}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{autonum}
\usepackage[compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{usebib}

\newbibfield{publisher}

\newcommand{\fullcitebook}[1]{%
  \citefullauthor{#1}, ``\usebibentry{#1}{title}'', \usebibentry{#1}{publisher},
  \usebibentry{#1}{year}%
}

\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\bibinput{\jobname}

\begin{document} 

\cite{goossens93}

\fullcitebook{goossens93}.

\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}

A few notes before showing the output:

forget getting what natbib doesn't provide, for instance the authors' names;
you need to craft yourself the full citation style based on the entry type;
filecontents is no longer needed as its functionality has been put into the LaTeX kernel;
unsrt should not be used with natbib;
unsrtnat is surely not the best style for a thesis (it is never the best style, actually).

I renamed the .bib file with \jobname in order not to risk clobbering my files.

Final note
Never use packages that rely on etextools. It's buggy and clashes with kernel macros. There are other tools for automatic numbering of referenced equations, if you really want to.

Could you have a look at my new question?
